# Latex - Multirow and Linebreak within array

Tags: arrays, multirow

How to Linebreak and center the following

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Kodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Sprache
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}
    SUBSET-SUM := $\left \{ \begin{array}{c|c} < x_1,\dots ,x_n,t > & x_1,\dots ,x_n,t \in \mathbb{N} \text{ und es existiert eine Teilmenge } I \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\} \text{ mit } \sum_{i \in I} x_i = t
    \end{array} \right \}$.
\end{document}
```

If i compile this, i cannot read the outcome as it is outside my paper boundries.

I'd like it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site, but please provide something that compiles.

Comment: It is not exactly clear how you want it to look, but here shows how to break it into lines and colums: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item SUBSET-SUM := $\left \{ \begin{array}{c|c}
< x_1,\dots ,x_n,t >  & x_1,\dots ,x_n,t \in \mathbb{N} \\ &\text{  und es existiert eine Teilmenge} \\ I \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\} & \text{ mit } \sum_{i \in I} x_i = t
\end{array} \right \}$.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks...i edited my first post so it should be clear now, how i'd like it to look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more solution, with use of `array` package and `m` column type:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Kodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Sprache
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    SUBSET-SUM : = 
        $\left \{ \begin{array}{c|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{0.55\textwidth}}
        \langle x_1,\dots ,x_n,t\rangle 
            &   $x_1,\dots ,x_n,t \in \mathbb{N}$  
                und es existiert eine Teilmenge 
                $I \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$ 
                mit 
                $\sum_{i \in I} x_i = t$
    \end{array} \right\}$.
\end{document}
```

it gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, too ... this looks even simpler then the one above

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,stackengine}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\def\stacktype{L}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item SUBSET-SUM := $\left\{ 
< x_1,\dots ,x_n,t >  \Bigg|\, \stackanchor{x_1,\dots ,x_n,t \in \mathbb{N} 
  \text{ und es existiert eine}} {\text{Teilmenge } I \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\} \text{ mit } 
  \displaystyle\sum_{i \in I} x_i = t}
 \right \}$.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ... didn't expect it to be that 'difficult'